# calculate the sum with in a selected date range for unique ids using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, automation

I have been trying to automate my excel workbooks into one consolidated sheet using VBA code.
the module that i am stuck with is to calculate the sum of sales with in a specific date range for the respective unique IDs.
my code seems to be right but i am always getting the answer as 0.
Kindly help me fix this code.
start column is the date that i am trying to match from a different sheet
last column is always in the column H of the same sheet where the start column is present. and these start and last column values are dates, i have the unique primary key and its sales respectively.

```
Sub ConsolidateData(fullInventoryPath As String, salesPath As String, productsPath As String, consolidatedPath As String)
Dim fullInventoryWorkbook As Workbook
Dim salesWorkbook As Workbook
Dim productsWorkbook As Workbook
Dim consolidatedWorkbook As Workbook
Dim fullInventorySheet As Worksheet
Dim salesSheet As Worksheet
Dim productsSheet As Worksheet
Dim consolidatedSheet As Worksheet
Dim uniqueFSN As Collection
Dim fsnCode As Variant
Dim fsnRowsSales As Range
Dim fsnRowSale As Range
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set fullInventoryWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fullInventoryPath)
Set salesWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(salesPath)
Set productsWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(productsPath)
On Error GoTo 0

If fullInventoryWorkbook Is Nothing Or salesWorkbook Is Nothing Or productsWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error opening one or more workbooks. Check the file paths and try again.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Set fullInventorySheet = fullInventoryWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set salesSheet = salesWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set productsSheet = productsWorkbook.Sheets(1)

On Error Resume Next
Set consolidatedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(consolidatedPath)
On Error GoTo 0

If consolidatedWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    Set consolidatedWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    consolidatedWorkbook.SaveAs consolidatedPath
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set consolidatedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(consolidatedPath)
On Error GoTo 0

If consolidatedWorkbook Is Nothing Then
    Set consolidatedWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    consolidatedWorkbook.SaveAs consolidatedPath
End If

On Error Resume Next
Set consolidatedSheet = consolidatedWorkbook.Sheets("ConsolidatedSheet")
On Error GoTo 0

If consolidatedSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set consolidatedSheet = consolidatedWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, consolidatedWorkbook.Sheets(consolidatedWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    consolidatedSheet.Name = "ConsolidatedSheet"
End If

consolidatedSheet.Cells.ClearContents

If consolidatedSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "" Then
    With consolidatedSheet
        .Cells(3, 1).Value = "Unique FSN"
        .Cells(3, 2).Value = "Google SKU"
        .Cells(3, 3).Value = "Description"
        .Cells(3, 4).Value = "Actual Inventory"
        .Cells(3, 5).Value = "Daily Run Rate"
        .Cells(3, 6).Value = "Last 7 Days Sales"
        .Cells(3, 7).Value = "Sales - DateRange"
        .Cells(3, 8).Value = "Estimated Inventory"
    End With
End If

Set uniqueFSN = New Collection

For rowCounter = 2 To salesSheet.Cells(salesSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    AddToUniqueFSN uniqueFSN, salesSheet.Cells(rowCounter, 4).Value
Next rowCounter

For Each fsnCode In uniqueFSN
    Set fsnRowsSales = salesSheet.Columns(4).Find(fsnCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    Dim fsnRowProducts As Range
    Set fsnRowProducts = productsSheet.Columns(1).Find(fsnCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not fsnRowsSales Is Nothing And Not fsnRowProducts Is Nothing Then
        For Each fsnRowSale In fsnRowsSales
            Dim consolidatedRow As Long
            consolidatedRow = consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 1).Value = fsnCode
            consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 2).Value = productsSheet.Cells(fsnRowProducts.Row, 2).Value
            consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 3).Value = productsSheet.Cells(fsnRowProducts.Row, 3).Value

            Dim inventoryCount As Variant
            inventoryCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(fullInventorySheet.Columns(4), fsnCode, fullInventorySheet.Columns(9))
            consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 4).Value = inventoryCount

            Dim latest7DaysSales As Double
            Dim last7DaysRange As Range
            Set last7DaysRange = salesSheet.Range(salesSheet.Cells(fsnRowSale.Row, 8), salesSheet.Cells(fsnRowSale.Row, 14))
            
            latest7DaysSales = WorksheetFunction.Sum(last7DaysRange)
            consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 6).Value = latest7DaysSales

            If latest7DaysSales <> 0 Then
                Dim dailyRunRate As Double
                dailyRunRate = latest7DaysSales / 7
                consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 5).Value = Round(dailyRunRate, 2)
            End If
            
            AddEstimatedInventoryColumn consolidatedSheet, fullInventorySheet, salesSheet, fsnCode, consolidatedRow
        Next fsnRowSale
    End If
Next fsnCode

FormatConsolidatedSheet consolidatedSheet

consolidatedWorkbook.Save
```

End Sub

Sub AddEstimatedInventoryColumn(consolidatedSheet As Worksheet, fullInventorySheet As Worksheet, salesSheet As Worksheet, fsnCode As Variant, consolidatedRow As Long)
' Find the FSN code in the Full Inventory Sheet
Dim fsnRowFI As Range
Set fsnRowFI = fullInventorySheet.Columns(4).Find(fsnCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

```
If Not fsnRowFI Is Nothing Then
    ' Get the value from cell K2 in the Full Inventory Sheet
    Dim dateValue As Variant
    dateValue = fullInventorySheet.Range("K2").Value

    ' Check if the value is not empty
    If dateValue <> "" Then
        ' Extract the date from the string "2023-12-27T09:00:48.054+05:30"
        Dim dateParts() As String
        dateParts = Split(dateValue, "T")

        ' Check if the date part is present
        If UBound(dateParts) >= 0 Then
            ' Try to convert the extracted date part to a Date
            Dim startDate As Date
            If IsDate(dateParts(0)) Then
                ' If the string is already a valid date, use it directly
                startDate = CDate(dateParts(0))

                Dim formattedDate As String
                formattedDate = Format(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
            Else
                MsgBox "Invalid date in cell K2 of Full Inventory sheet.", vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid date format in cell K2 of Full Inventory sheet.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' Find the column index for the start date in the Sales Sheet header
    Dim startColumn As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    startColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(formattedDate, salesSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the start column is found
    If startColumn > 0 Then
        ' Find the last column with data in the Sales Sheet
        lastColumn = 8
        ' Display startColumn and lastColumn after setting lastColumn
        MsgBox "Start Column: " & startColumn & vbCrLf & "Last Column: " & lastColumn, vbInformation
      
        ' Loop through each row with the specified FSN in the sales sheet
        Dim salesSum As Double
        Dim i As Long
        Dim fsnRowSale As Range
        Dim fsnRowsSales As Range
        
        Set fsnRowsSales = salesSheet.Columns(4).Find(fsnCode, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Do
            If Not fsnRowsSales Is Nothing Then
                ' Reset salesSum for each FSN
                salesSum = 0
        
                ' Loop through each row in fsnRowsSales
                For Each fsnRowSale In fsnRowsSales
                    ' Loop through the sales data for the specified date column
                    For i = startColumn To lastColumn
                        Dim currentValue As Variant
                        ' Convert text to numeric using Val function
                        currentValue = Val(salesSheet.Cells(fsnRowSale.Row, i).Value)
        
                        ' Display additional information for debugging
                        MsgBox "Current Value at row " & fsnRowSale.Row & ", column " & i & ": " & currentValue, vbInformation
        
                        ' Convert text to numeric using Val function
                        salesSum = salesSum + currentValue
                    Next i
                Next fsnRowSale
        
                ' Display the calculated NewSales
                MsgBox "NewSales: " & salesSum, vbInformation
        
                ' Store the aggregated sales value in memory (do not update the sheet yet)
                ' Use an appropriate variable or array to store this information in memory
        
                ' Once you finish looping through all FSNs, update the consolidated sheet
                ' Assuming consolidatedRow is the appropriate row for each FSN
                consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 7).Value = salesSum
        
                ' Subtract the aggregated sales sum from the inventory available in units in the Consolidated Sheet
                Dim inventoryAvailable As Variant
                inventoryAvailable = consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 4).Value ' Assuming Inventory Available column is in column 4
                Dim estimatedInventory As Double
                estimatedInventory = inventoryAvailable - salesSum
        
                ' Set the estimated inventory in the new column (column 7)
                consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 8).Value = estimatedInventory
            Else
                ' Handle the case where fsnRowsSales is Nothing
                MsgBox "No matching rows found in Sales sheet for the specified FSN code.", vbExclamation
            End If
        
            ' Find the next occurrence of fsnCode in the salesSheet
            Set fsnRowsSales = salesSheet.Columns(4).FindNext(fsnRowsSales)
        Loop While Not fsnRowsSales Is Nothing And fsnRowsSales.Row <> fsnRowsSales.Cells(1, 1).Row


    Else
        ' Handle the case where the start column is not found
        MsgBox "Start column date not found in Sales sheet header.", vbExclamation
    End If
Else
    consolidatedSheet.Cells(consolidatedRow, 8).Value = "FSN Code Not Found in Inventory Data"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: What's the value of `fsnCode`?  Using just the code you've supplied it doesn't have a value.

Comment: Also the first line of your `Do` loop sets `salesSum` to 0, so it will reset to 0 on each iteration of the loop.  You `Do` loop doesn't have a loop either so should throw an error?  Can you post the whole code please and maybe a table of the data it's looking at - or a mock up of the data if you can't show the actual data.

Comment: Excel's Power Query is very capable of merging many workbooks into a single table if the data structure is constant amongst each workbook (same field names and worksheet structure). Once you have your consolidated sheet you can even then use the same Power Query to transform your data to get the totals you are seeking. While VBA can be powerful when used appropriately, it's often the goto tool when there are sharper ones in the box.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Sure Darren!! Thanks for your time. I am setting up the salesSum to 0, assuming that it will not get accumulated for the next unique FSN code. Also, the data that it will be looking at is a sales report column index number 1 containing the primary Key (FSN) and the sales data spanning from column H to BN, but my daterange is from (H:K) only , i need the sales for the each unique FSN codes in the consolidated table.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs , yes Davis I agree. I'm uncertain of how it can be used while automating a report.

Comment: In your part of your code cannot be checked values for `startColumn` and `lastColumn`. If you add additional important information pls. dont do it in comments, rather edit your question. Furthermore the `Find` method returns a single cell, so the `For Each` loop not really necessary.

Comment: Do you mean that when you displaying the cells values they are valid numbers (`currentValue`), but `salesSum` is 0?

Comment: Yes @Blackcat actually to make sure of it i am also converting the values to numeric datatype before the aggregation step. I am still getting the sales sum as 0.